# naming directory after email under linux

Tags: linux

Linux does allows me to name a directory like

```
 test@gmail.com
```

I do not care about compatibility with other OSs. Is it OK to name a directory like this under Linux? There are quite a few pages on the web saying it's better to stick to alphanumeric and `_`.

Does it really matter in a modern OS like Linux though? I agree some applications might have some trouble reading these directories, but I do not really care about other applications. The only application I care about is the one that I am writing and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be fine. In fact, it's even the standard naming scheme for some uses. For example:

```
$ ls -d /usr/share/locale/*@*
/usr/share/locale/be@latin        /usr/share/locale/sr@ijekavian
/usr/share/locale/ca@valencia     /usr/share/locale/sr@ijekavianlatin
/usr/share/locale/en@boldquot     /usr/share/locale/sr@latin
/usr/share/locale/en@quot         /usr/share/locale/sr@Latn
/usr/share/locale/en@shaw         /usr/share/locale/sr_RS@latin
/usr/share/locale/en_US@piglatin  /usr/share/locale/uz@cyrillic
/usr/share/locale/sr@ije
```

In general it is a very good idea to avoid whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) in your file names and also to avoid characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions or shell globs (e.g. `\*$^()[]{}` etc.). However, I don't know of any cases where `@` will cause any issues, at least not on a Linux system.